# Why do require and fs.existSync use different relative paths

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code here:

```
if(fs.existsSync('./example/example.js')){
    cb(require('../example/example.js'));
}else{
    cb();
}
```

Why should `fs.existSync` be using a different directory than `require`?

This would be the directory tree excluding things not needed... (I am using express btw)

```
\example
    example.js
\routes
    index.js <-- this is the one where I am using this code
app.js <-- this one requires index.js and calls its functions using app.get('/example',example.index);
```

Comment: I don't understand the 'close' votes, I think it's a proper question.

Comment: It is a proper question -.-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The path you use for `require` is relative to the file in which you call `require` (so relative to `routes/index.js`); the path you use for `fs.existsSync()` (and the other `fs` functions) is relative to the current working directory (which is the directory that was current when you started `node`, provided that your app doesn't execute [`fs.chdir`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory) to change it).

As for the reason of this difference, I can only guess, but `require` is a mechanism for which some 'extra' logic w.r.t. finding other modules makes sense. It should also not be influenced by runtime changes in the application, like the aforementioned `fs.chdir`.

Answer (score 6):

Since the relative path to a file is relative to `process.cwd()`, as mentioned in [this link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths). You can use `path.resolve` to resolve the path relative to the location as below:

```
const path = require('path');

const desiredPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './file-location');
console.log(fs.existsSync(desiredPath)); // returns true if exists
```